# Code Coverage of DDSPublisher.java using EMMA

Tags: publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service

I am working in Linux platform ,implementing Opensplice DDS with Java using  Eclipse as IDE. Publishesr and Subscribers of main classes are getting executed .Currently working in code coverage part  using the tool EMMA .I have created the build file using ant script and created the targets for EMMA,At present 'm facing issue as mentioned below,
This is the  content at console:

```
[emmajava] # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
[emmajava] #
[emmajava] #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00f3a97a, pid=3580, tid=2472213360
[emmajava] #
[emmajava] # JRE version: 6.0_20-b20
[emmajava] # Java VM: OpenJDK Client VM (19.0-b06 mixed mode linux-x86 )
[emmajava] # Derivative: IcedTea6 1.9.1
[emmajava] # Distribution: Custom build (Wed Oct 13 22:53:35 UTC 2010)
[emmajava] # Problematic frame:
[emmajava] # V  [libjvm.so+0x20b97a]
[emmajava] #
   I would like to know how to use the Opensplice DDS with EMMA coverage?
```

Should i wanna change any of the  configurations ?Finally is it possible to make code
coverage in DDS implementation ? If any body else is aware about this issue, please guide me to proceed it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you try switching to the Sun/Oracle Java JDK as opposed to OpenJDK?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I have tried Sun JDK instead of OpenJDK.but i got same that fatal error.can anyone guide me how to proceed it.

Comment: Please get us a stack trace.  Attach with `gdb` before encountering this failure.